# react native run-ios build failed because 'LogSeverity'

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile-application

```
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "0.55.4",
```

this is my react native version
when im try to run project on mac os with run-ios project open in similatur but, im having truble with build and it be failed im looking every where but no answer.

im putting the errors below.

```
/Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/glog/src/glog/logging.h:638:1: 
error: unknown type name 'LogSeverity'
LogSeverity NormalizeSeverity(LogSeverity s);
^
/Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/glog/src/glog/logging.h:638:31: 
error: unknown type name 'LogSeverity'
LogSeverity NormalizeSeverity(LogSeverity s);
                              ^
/Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/glog/src/glog/logging.h:1163:42:     error: unknown type name 'LogSeverity'
  LogMessage(const char* file, int line, LogSeverity severity, int ctr,
                                          ^
/Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/glog/src/glog/logging.h:1181:42:         
error: unknown type name 'LogSeverity'
 LogMessage(const char* file, int line, LogSeverity severity);
                                         ^
 /Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/glog/src/glog/logging.h:1186:42: 
error: unknown type name 'LogSeverity'
LogMessage(const char* file, int line, LogSeverity severity, LogSink* sink,
                                        ^
/Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/glog/src/glog/logging.h:1192:42: 
error: unknown type name 'LogSeverity'
LogMessage(const char* file, int line, LogSeverity severity,
                                        ^
/Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/glog/src/glog/logging.h:1198:42: 
error: unknown type name 'LogSeverity'
LogMessage(const char* file, int line, LogSeverity severity,
                                        ^
/Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/glog/src/glog/logging.h:1242:41: 
error: unknown type name 'LogSeverity'
void Init(const char* file, int line, LogSeverity severity,
                                       ^
/Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/glog/src/glog/logging.h:1249:30: 
error: use of undeclared identifier 'NUM_SEVERITIES'
static int64 num_messages_[NUM_SEVERITIES];  /
/ under log_mutex
                         ^
/Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/glog/src/glog/logging.h:1275:3: 
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'google::LogMessage'
LogMessage(__FILE__, __LINE__, severity).stream() << msg;
^          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/glog/src/glog/logging.h:1202:3: 
note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const int' 
to 'const google::CheckOpString' for 3rd argument
LogMessage(const char* file, int line, const CheckOpString& result);
 ^
/Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/glog/src/glog/logging.h:1174:3: 
note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were 
provided
 LogMessage(const char* file, int line);
  ^
/Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/glog/src/glog/logging.h:1258:3: 
note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 3 were 
provided
 LogMessage(const LogMessage&);
 ^
/Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/glog/src/glog/logging.h:1304:47: 
error: unknown type name 'LogSeverity'
 ErrnoLogMessage(const char* file, int line, LogSeverity severity, int ctr,
                                             ^
/Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/glog/src/glog/logging.h:1331:41: 
error: unknown type name 'LogSeverity'
GOOGLE_GLOG_DLL_DECL void FlushLogFiles(LogSeverity min_severity);
                                        ^
 /Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/glog/src/glog/logging.h:1336:47: 
error: unknown type name 'LogSeverity'
GOOGLE_GLOG_DLL_DECL void FlushLogFilesUnsafe(LogSeverity min_severity);
                                              ^
/Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/glog/src/glog/logging.h:1343:45: 
error: unknown type name 'LogSeverity'
GOOGLE_GLOG_DLL_DECL void SetLogDestination(LogSeverity severity,
                                             ^
/Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/glog/src/glog/logging.h:1352:41: 
error: unknown type name 'LogSeverity'
GOOGLE_GLOG_DLL_DECL void SetLogSymlink(LogSeverity severity,
                                        ^


 ** BUILD FAILED **


 The following commands produced analyzer issues:

    Analyze Base/RCTModuleMethod.mm normal x86_64
  (1 command with analyzer issues)

 The following build commands failed:
   CompileC
```

> /Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/raw_logging.o glog/src/raw_logging.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       CompileC /Users/peyman/Desktop/myproject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/signalhandler.o glog/src/signalhandler.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   (2 failures)
>   "

- node version : 10.8.0
- watchman version : 4.9.0
- and im using the latest version of xcode
- running mac os on vmware
- main windows is 10

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## fixed it with

in ios folder im delete pods
and podfile.lock

and then pod install

Answer (score 2):

Your project ios folder please delete below file and folder:

- pods folder
- podfile.lock
- then install pod from ios folder like {path}=> pod install